# The finiteness of the fundamental group of a closed Ricci-flat manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry

If $M$ is a Ricci-flat closed Riemannian manifold with $H^1(M,\mathbb R^n)=0$, can we show the fundamental group of $M$ is finite?

Comment: No, we cannot, because it would be false even for flat manifolds. Google  "Hantzsche-Wendt manidolds."